# Getting Coffeescript to Find the Right Div // Stripe Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, stripe-payments

With the help of Ryan Bates' tutorial, I was able to set up Stripe. Now, I'm trying to allow users to update their credit card information.

Right now I'm hung up on being able invoke stripe when the action button is clicked. The possible reason for this is that I've hacked together the coffeescript by basically copying Ryan's code for making a new credit card.

Here's the form I'm using to PUT the new credit card info

```
<%= form_tag("/users/update_card", :method => "put", :class => "edit_user", :id => "change_card" ) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :stripe_card_token %>

  <div id="stripe_error" class="alert">   
      <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
      <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
      <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
    </div>


  <%= submit_tag("Update My Credit Card", :class => "button") %>
```

Here's the Coffeescript I'm using. The first half covers the registration of new users(which works) and the second half, starting at changecard.setupForm(), doesn't

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()

subscription =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_user').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        subscription.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_user')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)

changecard.setupForm()

changecard =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#change_card').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        subscription.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#change_card')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

Here's my update_card action

```
  def update_card
  @user = current_user
  cu = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripe_customer_token)
  cu.card = params[:stripe_customer_token] # obtained with Stripe.js
  cu.save
  redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
  end
```

Thanks for sticking through this far! Your thoughts are greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

After stepping through the javascript, it paused on

```
changecard.setupForm()
```

That's the line I started with :P. The error is

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setupForm' of undefined
```

it seems like changecard is not properly defined using the coffeescript I've put above. I'm not sure how to change it though, any help greatly appreciated!

**Edit 2**

With javascript debugging, here's the final code, which seems to deliver the stripe_card_token

```
**# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()
  changecard.setupForm()
subscription =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_user').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        subscription.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_user')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
changecard =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#change_card').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        changecard.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, changecard.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#change_card')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)**
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Hi Beerlington, it seems like the stripe_card_token is not being filled in when it's submitted. It's as though the coffescript starting at changecard is being ignored -- i.e button doesn't disable, if I enter nothing, no error shows up. 

Is there some piece of info I could provide that would help reveal the error a bit better?

Comment: Are you getting an JS or Ruby errors?

Comment: I think it's JS errors--the Ruby seems to function, though the stripe_card_token is nil, maybe because the Javascript isn't acting.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the Javascript with firebug or equivalent JS debug tools?

Comment: Do you see any JS errors in the console?

Comment: ...Excellent idea! it spat back the error : 

uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setupForm' of undefined on changecard.setupForm . I am guessing changecard is not properly defined, though I'm not sure what to change

Comment: Op, all I had to do was to move the changecard.setupForm to the very top, under subscriptions.setupForm. Thanks for walking me through this guys, I look forward to the day that I'm skilled enough to pay it forward! Please provide an answer and I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2

With javascript debugging, here's the final code, which seems to deliver the stripe_card_token

```
**# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()
  changecard.setupForm()
subscription =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_user').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        subscription.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_user')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
changecard =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#change_card').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        changecard.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, changecard.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#change_card')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)**
```